# FIR filter unit step response

Tags: convolution, signal-processing

Given a FIR filter with impulse response:

$$ 
h(n) = \begin{cases}1, &0 \leq n < 5\\
-1, &10 \leq n < 15 \\
0, &\text{otherwise}\end{cases}
$$

What would be the right approach to calculate the filter discrete unit step response?

I don’t understand..how can I apply convolution to these 2 functions? Especially since the impulse response is expressed in that way...

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

For a discrete-time LTI system we have $$s[n] = \sum_{k = -\infty}^{n}h[k]$$And $$h[n] = s[n] - s[n-1]$$ Where $s[n]$ is the unit step response and $h[n]$ is the unit impulse response.